# How to make atutor not check for user's browser language?

Tags: php, browser, browser-detection

as you know atutor checks for user's browser first to detect the language and if it cannot find it, it uses the default language set by the administrator. I searched and found the code, do you know how I can change it so that atutor directly uses the default language and not check for user's first?

```
    /**
* Tries to detect the user's current language preference/setting from (in order):
* _GET, _POST, _SESSION, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, HTTP_USER_AGENT. If no match can be made
* then it tries to detect a default setting (defined in config.inc.php) or a fallback
* setting, false if all else fails.
* @access   public
* @return   boolean|Language    Returns a Language Object matching the user's current session.
*                               Returns FALSE if a valid Language Object cannot be found
*                               to match the request
* @see      getLanguage()
*/
function getMyLanguage() {
    global $addslashes, $db; 

    if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['lang']) && isset($this->availableLanguages[$_GET['lang']])) {
        $language = $this->getLanguage($_GET['lang']);

        if ($language) {
            return $language;
        }

    } 
    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['lang']) && isset($this->availableLanguages[$_POST['lang']])) {
        $language = $this->getLanguage($_POST['lang']);

        if ($language) {
            return $language;
        }

    } 
    if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['lang']) && !empty($_SESSION['lang']) && isset($this->availableLanguages[$_SESSION['lang']])) {
        $language = $this->getLanguage($_SESSION['lang']);

        if ($language) {
            return $language;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {

        // Language is not defined yet :
        // try to find out user's language by checking its HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
        $accepted    = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $acceptedCnt = count($accepted);
        reset($accepted);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $acceptedCnt; $i++) {
            foreach ($this->availableLanguages as $codes) {
                foreach ($codes as $language) {
                    if ($language->isMatchHttpAcceptLanguage($accepted[$i])) {
                        return $language;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

        // Language is not defined yet :
        // try to find out user's language by checking its HTTP_USER_AGENT
        foreach ($this->availableLanguages as $codes) {
            foreach ($codes as $language) {
                if ($language->isMatchHttpUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                    return $language;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    // Didn't catch any valid lang : we use the default settings
    if (isset($this->availableLanguages[DEFAULT_LANGUAGE])) {
        $language = $this->getLanguage(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_CHARSET);

        if ($language) {
            return $language;
        }
    }

    // fail safe
    if (isset($this->availableLanguages[$this->default_lang])) {
        $language = $this->getLanguage($this->default_lang, $this->default_charset);

        if ($language) {
            return $language;
        }
    }

    // else pick one at random:
    reset($this->availableLanguages);

    $unknown_language = current($this->availableLanguages);

    if (!$unknown_language) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return current($unknown_language);
}

function getAvailableLanguages() {
    return $this->availableLanguages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to comment out this chunk:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {

    // Language is not defined yet :
    // try to find out user's language by checking its HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
    $accepted    = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    $acceptedCnt = count($accepted);
    reset($accepted);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $acceptedCnt; $i++) {
        foreach ($this->availableLanguages as $codes) {
            foreach ($codes as $language) {
                if ($language->isMatchHttpAcceptLanguage($accepted[$i])) {
                    return $language;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```